# Error with custom definition

Tags: preamble

I am working on a file on multiple computers, laptop and PC.  I am using TexStudio, same version on both.  On the laptop, the file compiles fine, but on the PC I am having trouble.  On the PC, when I try to pdflatex it, I get an error:

"Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 79 \include{chapter 1}"

When I go to line 79, it is a custom definition defined as follows:

```
\def\imod#1{\allowbreak\mkern6mu({\operator@font mod}\,\,#1)}
```

Again, this file compiles fine on the laptop, but on the PC, it has a problem with this line.  Am I missing a space or comma or something?

Comment: You've provided us with a broken brick in your city of code. It's really a guessing game at this point with this amount of information. Ideally we'd like to see a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem. We want to copy-and-paste the code into our editor, press the compile button, and voila! ...it should explode in the same way you see it exploding. We like that, really.

Comment: Might be a bit difficult, since I have a master file and 7 chapter files that are called in to run in the master file (working on thesis).  Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: How are you syncing between the computers? Are they running the same TeX distribution (MiKTeX or TeXLive)? Have you tried updating the TeX distribution on both computers (or maybe just on the broken one first)? What OS are you using?

Comment: I am syncing with dropbox, that is I copy and paste the same set of files to each computer when I am using them.  MiKTeX is configured to update on the fly on both, and I'm using Windows 7 on both.  I will try updating MiKTeX....

Comment: don't put spaces in your file names use chapter1 not chapter 1

Comment: The first thing I usually try when encountering issues like this is to delete all the temporary files - basically, everything except the `.tex` file(s). Its possible the syncing with Dropbox might have caught the build at a weird time

Comment: although you are synching with dropbox, you probably don't copy the document class and all packages.  get a copy of the log from each machine, then go through them side by side, comparing the version numbers reported by the class file and packages.  when this happens to me, it's almost always a version discrepancy.

Comment: @ barbara beeton, I just did this and the first line of the log file appears to show different versions of pdfTeX, even though in TeXStudio, the version of the editor is the same.  So I'm assuming this is an issue.....how does this get fixed?

Comment: @Mat update MiKTeX - Start Menu->MiKTeX 2.9->Maintenence (Admin)->Update (Admin) (I'm assuming you've installed MiKTeX the default way, and I'm pretty sure that's the right Start Menu directory...)

Comment: Note that the fact that this is from a large project does not make it impossible to create an MWE. Indeed, the bigger the project, the more important and useful creating an MWE is. (I frequently solve problems by creating such things without ever needing to post a question.) The link in Werner's original comment explains how to go about creating an MWE and what should go into it.